# Wire Gauge of Stranded Wire

Tags: electrical, appliances, wire

Is the wire gauge the same for solid and stranded wire? I need to check the wire gauge of some stranded wire. Can I use standard wire strippers to check the  gauge of stranded wire?

Comment: There is a slight difference but strippers will get you there.

Comment: Just read the insulation - it's typically marked every 2-3 feet with all the information you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the size difference is ~5% larger with stranded than solid depending on the strand count. The sizes are far enough apart that the strippers if in good shape are a great tool for measuring.